# Removing SQL user from a server, multiple owners on a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

I need to completely remove a user from a server.
I can remove any entires for that user in specific tables (tied to an app), I know how to remove from individual dataabses and the server, but on several databases, the users shema owns a table (that is also owned by several other users) so I cannot drop that user.

I cannot drop the table, other users need it.
I cannot just change ownership of the table, as again, other users need it. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how it works, alter schema CAN be used to transfer ownership from jsut one specific user, right?

```sql
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER OtherUserSchema.TargetTable;  
GO
```

Will this affect ONLY the other users schema on the TargetTable, and leave other schemas that own that table?

Naturally, dropping the user won't work since I get:

> Cannot drop schema 'BDR\TPRGOMET' because it is being referenced by object 'xkartkont'.

Does a schema with domain name cause any issues?

Comment: *"the users shema owns a table (that is also owned by several other users)"* That sentence doesn't make sence; an object/schema can only have one owner, not many.

Comment: *"I cannot just change ownership of the table, as again, other users need it."* Presumably are you using permission chaining here. If you are `DROP`ping a `USER` you'll need to change all the owners anyway, so provided you change all the objects owned by the `USER` to be dropped to be owned by another `USER` then that permission chaining will continue to work.

Comment: To explain, I ran this command on a dtaabse to see what the schema owns:    'DECLARE  @SchemaName NVARCHAR(100) = 'MSPM\TPRGOMET';
     SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(@SchemaName) AND type NOT IN ('S');'        and I got multiple table owners?

Comment: Also, I cannot evne run the alter schema command, as It points to incorrect sintax. That being the \

Comment: *"I got multiple table owners"* You can't have, again, an object can only have one owner. The owner of an object is defined in the `principle_id` column, and that is an `int`, so it's **impossible** for it to have multiple values.

Comment: Further clarification:

I need to completely remove a user from a server and then later add the same user back
Alter schema command give my synatx error becaue of the schema name
I could transfer ownership of the schema to another user, then remove the user, but that would leave the shema with the same name on the databases and that will casue issues if I try to add the same user back

Comment: *" need to completely remove a user from a server and then later add the same user back"* This sounds like an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info) now.

Comment: It's an AD user that was already on the server before, but quit working and was "removed" (inactive), now it's back and needed assigment to different databases. I do not manage the AD and the AD guys assure me everything is fine with the user. User cannot log in on SQL server, despite being on the SQL server. At this point my only solution is to either remove/re-create the user or create a new one.

Comment: Did they delete that AD user on the domain? If so, then even if the name is the same, their SID won't be.

Comment: I checked. They never delete  an AD user, just disable it. We also never removed the user from the server. So unless disabling changes the SID, this should be OK. All I did was make sure the sql user was active and then gave it permission to the specific databases it needs (and put some user data in those databases).

Comment: I would consult the SQL Server logs then to find out what the authentication error is; this is most certainly seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) now.

Comment: Login failed for user 'MSPM\tprgomet'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 192.168.252.4]
Strange. It is a windows login, under that name (except allcaps), but the server is using Case Insnsitive collation.

Comment: I still; suspect the SIDs don't match. Open a Powershell window and run`Get-AdUser -Identity "{AD User Name}" | Select sid`, then go to your SQL Server instance and run `SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE sid = SID_BINARY(N'{AD SID');`, obviously replacing the values in braces with the appropriate values; do you get a return value from your SQL? If not, then the SID has changed because the AD user was deleting and recreated.

Comment: The server was migrated before, so yes, the SID was to blame. I did (partially) drop the user and re-create it and it works now. I say partially, because the schema still exists on 5 databases and adding the user back on those 5 failed (thankfully he don't need those 5, but I still want to fix it). Note that I did alter authorization to move the schema to dbo before dropping the user. That schema is referrenced by an object (table), but I'm hesitant to drop it. This seems to be a base table and when I list all tables, it shows up multiple times with different schemas?

Comment: Thanks for everyone who helped. The SID was the problem (I think) and the schema/table mess just complicated things, but now the problem is solved.